# Is there any way to check, from a .hpp file, if C stdio functions are used in the corresponding .cpp file?

Tags: c++, c, c++17, compile-time

I have the following question. Supposing I have an header file `header.hpp` which is include in a `test.cpp` file. Is it possible to add instructions to the `header.hpp` file in order to check (maybe at compile time) if some C stdio functions are used in the `test.cpp` file and in positive case do something specific? For example something like:

`header.hpp`:

```
#ifndef HEAD
#define HEAD
#include <iostream>
if ( C stdio functions are used in test.cpp ){
  std::cout << "Hey" << "\n";
}
#endif
```

`test.cpp`

```
#include "header.hpp"
#include <cstdio>
int main(){
  printf( "Hello\n" ); // C stdio function has been used.
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
Hey
```

Comment: A header file is not an independent entity. Consider it a part of any cpp file it's included to (there is no difference if you just write content of header file right in the cpp file or leave it in a separate file, if you don't include the header elsewhere). So Your question boils down to - is there a way to pass in the first half of the file information what is contained in the second part of the file. AFAIK the answer is no (with exception to classes, where compilers technically put all member functions *after* the class declaration). You can, however, define a macro before `#include`..

Comment: ..and it will make the macro visible in the content of the included header

Comment: There's no way in the C++ language. A step in a build system could do it, but would probably mean compiling the source once to check for use and maybe a second time if a use was detected.

Comment: What if a function with IO implemented in another module is called by a function implemented in "test.cpp"? Should it be detected, too?

Comment: You seem to have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please [edit] your question and add _why_ you need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Neither C++, nor C, work like this, on a fundamental level.

An `#include` is logically equivalent to physically inserting the contents of the included file into the including file. Doing a cut and paste of your `header.hpp` into the beginning of your `test.cpp` replacing the `#include` accomplishes exactly the same thing.

The resulting code gets compiled from beginning to the end, in order.

When reading the header file, the C++ compiler has no knowledge, whatsoever, of something it hasn't read yet. An `#include` stops reading the file that it's in, and the included file gets read and compiled, before proceeding.